# Site is not updating because something is wrong with custom code. How to fix it?

Tags: functions

I really didnt know what a proper title for this question could be.

Anyways, I have this code in functions.php which is breaking my site

```
function wp_show_post_views(){
global $post;
$postid = $post->ID;
$output_views = get_transient('views' . $postid);
if( !is_object( $post ) || true === $output_views ) return;
if( function_exists( 'stats_get_csv' ) ){
    $args = array(
          'days'  => -1,
          'post_id'  => $postid
     );
     $postviews = stats_get_csv( 'postviews', $args );
     $output_views = $postviews['0']['views'];

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'postviews', $output_views);
    set_transient('views' . $postid ,$output_views,60*60);
}
echo $output_views;
}
```

I am calling it in my single.php as follows:

```
<?php wp_show_post_views(); ?>
```

In the front end, everything looks good. However, if I go to the backend and update some widgets, there are no changes in the front end. Once I remove the code, everything works fine.

So, I hope someone can tell me what is wrong with the code and if there is a way to fix it.

**EDIT:**
I narrow it down to this:

```
            $args = array(
              'days'  => -1,
              'post_id'  => $postid
         );
         $postviews = stats_get_csv( 'postviews', $args );
         $output_views = $postviews['0']['views'];
```

So, the error must be in there.

**EDIT: After enabling WP_DEBUG, I get his:**

```
[18-Sep-2013 19:44:36 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/user/public_html/domain.com/wp-includes/functions.php:2998) in /home/user/public_html/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/stats.php on line 433
[18-Sep-2013 19:44:36 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/user/public_html/domain.com/wp-includes/functions.php:2998) in /home/user/public_html/domain.com/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/stats.php on line 434
```

**EDIT: Found more erorrs:**

```
[18-Sep-2013 20:02:51 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/user/public_html/domain.com/wp-content/themes/2012.ffwd/functions.php on line 235
```

**EDIT:** This is line 235

```
    $postid = $post->ID;
```

I am also getting this error:

```
[18-Sep-2013 20:16:19 UTC] PHP Notice:  has_cap fue llamado con un argumento que estÃ¡ <strong>obsoleto</strong> desde la versiÃ³n 2.0! El uso de niveles de usuarios por plugins y temas estÃ¡ obsoleto. Usa los perfiles y capacidades en su lugar. in /home/user/public_html/domain.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2998
```

Translated:

```
[18-Sep-2013 20:16:19 UTC] PHP Notice:  has_cap was called with an argument who are <strong> obsolete </ strong> since version 2.0! The use of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use the profiles and capabilities instead. in /home/user/public_html/domain.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2998
```

Comment: Can you just check it for any errors by setting wp_debug to true in wp-config.php file?

Comment: activate the defoult theme and then try to  update

Comment: @Vinod Dalvi: I enabled wp_debug but I see no errors. Vickey: if I activate any other theme, it works again. Anyways, the site works if I disable the function. But I need to make that function work.

Comment: ok, I narrow it down to: please check original post

Comment: Is is possible that the error exists within the stats_get_csv() function. Again, enable error reporting. In your functions.php file at the very top add error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @Chris ok I added that to my functions and this is what I get: check original post.

Comment: Is there a `?>` at the end of your `functions.php` file?  If so, try removing it.  There may be whitespace characters after it, which you don't want.

Comment: @PatJ: Yes, there was a `?>` at the end of my `functions.php` I just removed it. However, the problem persists :( I found another error, see original post.

Comment: I'm going to assume `2012.ffwd` is your active theme.  Please add the function that contains line 235 into your question.

Comment: @PatJ yes thats the active theme. I just added the line 235 to my question.

Comment: The `Trying to get property of non-object` notice seems to indicate that `$post` is either not an object or (more likely) `null`.  Where are you getting `$post` from?

Comment: @PatJ I need to get the post id, so I am using this `$post->ID;` to get it. I am calling the function inside single.php

Comment: @PatJ After many many different tests. I started fresh with the `twentytwelve theme`, created a child theme with a `functions.php` file in it and added the `wp_show_post_views()` function. The problem persists. My conclusion is that there must be some issue with this function:  `stats_get_csv( 'postviews', $args );`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10665/discussion-between-gixty-and-pat-j)